# Facebook SSO for Android Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I have followed advice that seems to be working for others when trying to get SSO to work when Facebook app is also installed on device but I am still unable to get it to work.(The app loads but the Facebook login dialog disappears instantly.)  I have a valid hash key generated from this OSX terminal command which I also have given to Facebook. but it isn't working as it seems to be for others.

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

thanks!

Comment: The facebook sdk has a nice example to implement SSO. Search the github repo for HackBook example. Hope this helps.

Comment: the HackBook example is where I templated the origins of my Facebook App. But that was the last part of 2011. I will redownload and take a look.  thanks!

Comment: After using the latest Facebook Android sample project code, all was well with SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to generate Key Hash.

http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download/keyhash.zip

Comment: thanks Vipul, yes this generates the same Key Hash that I have been using. So the problem lies elsewhere.